# meaning of "grunt" when it comes to towing

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

The title of the humorous story is "The Sun got stuck"

> “I don't suppose you could give us a tow, could you, sister?”
>
> Luna's eyebrows shot up, “How? With what? The sun's 400 times larger than the moon, and even if I could give you a tow, it'd take me 8 light minutes to get there! And besides, I may have lowered it and put a supercharger in, but I'd never have enough **grunt** to tow it! Sorry, sis, but you're on your own. You can fix it, can't you?”

I tried the usual (Wiktionary, Merriam-Webster, The Free, Dictionary.com) and none of the definitions (foot soldier, sound, menial worker, fish, dessert), seem to match this kind of usage. What does *grunt* in this context mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Oxford Dictionary:

> 3 [mass noun] British informal mechanical power, especially in a motor
>   vehicle: what the big wagon needs is grunt, and the turbo does the
>   business

Grunt is being used to describe pulling (or towing) capability.  I found it in this article relating an entry in a [tractor pulling competition](http://m.stratfordpress.co.nz/news/tractors-grunt-and-strength/1441143/):

> He says it is about having the tractor with the most grunt, but adds that a lot of skill is also involved.

Answer (score 5):

In this context, *grunt* means *power* or *force*. In the context of engines in general, *grunt* often refers to the amount of *torque* that the engine can produce.